# Vue.JS conditional rendering revert changes made beyond the component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am wondering if it is possible to revert any changes made beyong the component element after the conditional rendering. Let me explain it.

Im using a CSS framework that makes changes to body tag (adds few classes) and adds a new div at the and of the body tag when the framework's element is loaded. The problem is that when I want to reuse this element again it wont show up, because some "leftovers" still exist.

Also I've discovered the following: when the Vue Component is not loaded, it leaves a comment in place. And when the component is loaded this comment is replaced by a component's template.

In my situation when the component is unloaded via v-if, the comment is not returned back. Too much text, I know, but I tried to explain it as detailed as I could.

Thus, the question: is there a way to revert(undo) changes that component did?

```js
<template>
    <div class="ui small modal" id="modal-edit-juxtaposition">
        <div class="ui header">
            Edit configuration
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="ui form">

                <div class="field">
                    <label>Database</label>
                    <div class="ui fluid selection loading dropdown" id="dbDropdown">
                        <div class="text"></div>
                        <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <button
                        class="ui primary button"
                >
                    Save
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: {
            orders_trans: {
                type: Object,
                required: true
            },
            buttons_trans: {
                type: Object,
                required: true
            }
        },

        mounted() {
            $('#modal-edit-juxtaposition').modal('show');
        },

        methods: {
            //
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Are you defining that component? Can you modify the destroyed event of the component to clean up after itself?

Comment: Yes, the component is in separate file. It has its data, props and methods.

Comment: You can define the destroy method on that component and within that revert any changes you made. If you provide some code we can probably give a working example.

Comment: Okey, I'll post component's src in a couple of minutes

Comment: there are some methods you can use to achieve that, if you take a look at the docs you can find the component lifecycle and the methods you can use to do certain things at a specific moment of that cycle. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram
But just as @JamesCoyle said before, it would be very useful you to post some code to explain the problem more clearly.

Comment: Between I've added the source code of the component.

Comment: @CarlosPisarello you mean I should use beforeDestroy or destroyed method?

Comment: Yes, but that depends on the kind of changes you did, when a component is unloaded via v-if it is actually destroyed and any changes made to that component are reverted, but if you want to perform actions to other component or other element when that component being unloaded is destroyed you should use that methods. Anyway, you should read a little bit about Vuex (A state managment pattern) to controll all the state from outside all components. It will allow you to define variables you can access from anywhere in your app and handle them. https://vuex.vuejs.org/

Comment: I am using VueX already :)

Comment: Oh and i also noticed you used Jquery to target '#modal-edit-juxtaposition', it's not recomended to use Jquery inside Vue due to the fact that the framework already replaces all the Jquery tools used to give developers and if you use them both they can colide and may cause problems. To target a component's element you should use this.$el.querySelector('#modal-edit-juxtaposition') in this case. the $el property returns the element inside the template tag of a component. have in count you can't target this.$el from created() or destroyed(), because there would be no template at that points